# 'window.fbAsyncInit' is not working on page load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-oauth

I want to integrate facebook oauth and for that I am loading javascript library but the code provided by facebook is not working for me.

I added this code in index.html and I am using angular js to render my app so on load all modules will get inject in **index.html**.

**This is the code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="fuse">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Fuse - Admin Theme</title>

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

        <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
        <!-- bower:css -->
        <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower styles dependencies -->
        <!-- endbower -->
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
        <!-- inject:css -->
        <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
        <!-- endinject -->
        <!-- endbuild -->


        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700italic,700,900,900italic'
              rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade
        your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <body md-theme="{{vm.themes.active.name}}" md-theme-watch ng-controller="IndexController as vm"
          class="{{state.current.bodyClass || ''}}">


        <!-- SPLASH SCREEN -->
        <ms-splash-screen id="splash-screen">
            <div class="center">
                <div class="logo">
                    <span>F</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Material Design Spinner -->
                <div class="spinner-wrapper">
                    <div class="spinner">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="gap"></div>
                            <div class="left">
                                <div class="half-circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="half-circle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / Material Design Spinner -->
            </div>
        </ms-splash-screen>
        <!-- / SPLASH SCREEN -->

        <div id="main" class="animate-slide-up" ui-view="main" layout="column"></div>

        <ms-theme-options></ms-theme-options>

        <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
        <!-- endbower -->
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
        <!-- inject:js -->
        <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
        <!-- endinject -->

        <!-- inject:partials -->
        <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
        <!-- endinject -->
        <!-- endbuild -->

    </body>
     <script>

                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                      appId      : '151468821996059',
                      xfbml      : true,
                      version    : 'v2.8'
                    });
                };

                (function(d, s, id){
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            </script>

</html>
```